# Suppress GTK signal when callback is triggered via code

Tags: c++, callback, gtk, gtkmm

**Gist**:

`handler_block` is useful on a case-by-case basis, but I'd rather call something at the beginning of the program to suppress a signal for all calls to `gtk_entry_set_text` and gtk_toggle_button_set_active. Is there a way?

---

**Background Info**:

My program is used to make Entities via a character creator dialog box with the following attributes:

Name - chosen from a predetermined list via GTKComboBoxes

Animation - also a GTKComboBox

Group - one of six radio buttons classifying the entity

Entities can be added - one starts with a blank Add dialog, fills in all fields, and submits. 

Entities can be edited via the Edit dialog, where all the fields listed above are initially filled in with the entity's current attributes. The edits are instantaneous (no Submit button on the Edit dialog) and the displayed Entity will appear different as soon as the new value from the combo or radio buttons is selected.

I have a callback connected to the Type entry and triggered by the "changed" signal. The callback seems to trigger whenever I set the entry text manually in code to show the entity being edited:

```
gtk_entry_set_text(GTK_ENTRY(name_entry), entity.name); // name is a char*
gtk_toggle_button_set_active(GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON (group_button_friendly), TRUE);
```

Yeah, there is a way with `g_signal_handler_block`, but that requires

1) getting the `gulong` that is created when you connect the signal in the first place.
`g_signal_connect(args);`
vs.
`gulong entry_handler_id = g_signal_connect(args);`

2) Using the block/unblock idiom for every single call. 

`g_signal_handler_block(args, entry_handler_id);`

`gtk_entry_set_text(args);`

`g_signal_handler_unblock(args, entry_handler_id);`

or worse,

`g_signal_handler_block(args, entry_handler_id);`

`fn_that_calls_gtk_entry_set_text();`

`g_signal_handler_unblock(args, entry_handler_id);`

Comment: Could you compare the text in the form to the "saved" info and just return? I don't know if there is a way to blank events from triggering. In an app im writing, I just have the on changed event or whatever write it's value out, basically meaning that you write what you just wrote back, but it didn't really get in the way for me (assuming you aren't doing anything special in your callbacks).

Comment: Instead of blocking your own handler like that, you can set some flag variable that tells the handler to do nothing. *[The reason why GTK+ emits signals even for changes from source code, is robustness, as I understand. E.g. two libraries (or a library and your own code) can connect to the same object and still see changes made by each other.]*

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, @doublep. I was going crazy and cursing the creators of this library, but it's good to know there's a reason behind this frustrating concept. I am currently using a bool called _suppress_callback, though that only addresses issue (1) and still requires me to bookend the offending function with two lines of code.

Comment: @senshikaze, I ended up comparing the callback value to the saved value as you suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `g_signal_handlers_block_matched`. If you set the mask to just `G_SIGNAL_MATCH_CLOSURE` with the closure used in the signal it should do the trick.

You'll have to look up the `signal_id` for the signal that is being emitted, but you should only need to do that once since the signal id is the same between all widgets, which is why the instance is required in the call as well.

And to unblock you want to use `g_signal_handlers_unblock_matched`.